# Membership ChangePassword (hashed) match current password against old password field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership, change-password

I am implementing a system where the user can Reset their password if they have forgotten it.

Once it is reset I want to give them the option of changing the password so that it will be something more memorable to them.

The password is hashed and if i enter in the correct old password and new password the password does change.

If I enter in the wrong old password and new password the password doesnt change.

Is there a way to match the old password with the old password field in code behind so I can throw up an error to the user to tell them what is wrong?

I have tried:

```
Dim currentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
currentUser.GetPassword()
```

But this won't work I think because the password is hashed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, but the ChangePassword method returns a bool (true if successful, false if not), so why not just throw up your  message on a false result?

Comment: Thanks Paul. My own fault really, I was Googling ChangePassword and the results were ChangePassword Class and not Method, but found that now and helped me out. Thanks.